# gazebo is not lunaching moveit package

Tags: gazebo, moveit, robotic-arm, manipulator

I have a ros noetic moveit package a robotic arm having `demo_gazebo.launch` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- MoveIt options -->
  <arg name="pipeline" default="ompl" doc="Planning pipeline to use with MoveIt"/>

  <!-- Gazebo options -->
  <arg name="gazebo_gui" default="true" doc="Start Gazebo GUI"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="false" doc="Start Gazebo paused"/>
  <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world" doc="Gazebo world file"/>
  <arg name="world_pose" default="-x 0 -y 0 -z 0 -R 0 -P 0 -Y 0" doc="Pose to spawn the robot at"/>

  <!-- Launch Gazebo and spawn the robot -->
  <include file="$(dirname)/gazebo.launch" pass_all_args="true"/>

  <!-- Launch MoveIt -->
  <include file="$(dirname)/demo.launch" pass_all_args="true">
    <!-- robot_description is loaded by gazebo.launch, to enable Gazebo features -->
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="false" />
    <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" value="ros_control" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

the robot perform well in rviz and reached the target point but when launching in gazebo get the following error

```
Error [parser.cc:488] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error Code 4 Msg: Required attribute[filename] in element[plugin] is not specified in SDF.
Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element <plugin>
Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element <model>
Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element <sdf>
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at this [tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/multiple_robot_arms/multiple_robot_arms_tutorial.html)? I wrote it to do what you need, but for dual arms. It may not be easy to catch the issue with just the input in the question. The tutorial has all the details. You need to delete what is for the second arm. If the problem persists after the tutorial, update the question, and I will follow up.